# Nested IF statements assistance

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested-if

I made a small workbook that exactly mimics the original formulas I posted.  The purpose of the workbook is to calculate the bonuses for each employee based on various inputted combinations (listed below).  Here is how my workbook is laid out:

1. Data Tab
2. Bonus Tab
3. Base Bonus Tab
4. Summary Tab

Picture of the Data tab that I utilize to input the different combinations:
[Data Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm5rJ.jpg)

List of the combinations:

- Employee % (cell B3) & Company % (cell B4) cells have numbers inputted = Combo 1 (range: 0%-100%)
- Employee $ (cell B5) & Company $ (cell B6) cells have numbers inputted =Combo 2 (range: $0-no limit)
- Base Salary (B2) is Yes & Employee % (cell B3) cells have been inputted = Combo 3 (Base Salary is either Yes or blank)
- Base Salary (B2) is Yes & Job Title (A8) & Employee % (cell B8) cell have been inputted = Combo 5

I use cell C1 for an IF statement to dictate which formula to use based on the combinations above. (ex. numbers in B5 & B6 = 1)

```
=IF(AND($B$2<>"",$A$8<>"",$B$8<>""),5,IF(AND($B$2<>"",$B$3<>""),3,IF($B$3<>"",1,IF($B$5<>"",2))))
```

Picture of the Bonus Tab: [Bonus Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov3wE.jpg)

Picture of the Base Bonus Tab: [Base Bonus Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHR9x.jpg)

Picture of the Summary Tab: [Summary Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INEo6.jpg)

I have created formulas for each combinations separately, but as soon as I try to combine them into one, I get the Too many arguments error message since combo 3 & combo 5 use false within the IF statement.  I am attempting to avoid making a calculations table and would prefer utilizing one formula on the summary tab by employee in column B.

I will further explain combo 3 specifically - If the base bonus is less than the regular bonus, than multiply the base bonus * Employee % + Company&Vendor bonus * Company %. If base bonus is more than regular bonus, than multiply regular bonus * Employee % + Company&Vendor bonus * Company %.

Example:

**Bobby**

Base Bonus $50 < Regular Bonus $100

$50 * 50% employee % = $25
+ $200 company + $0 vendor * 50% company = $100

Final answer is $125 if base bonus if < regular bonus

I will further explain combo 5 specifically - If the base bonus is less than the regular bonus, than multiply the base bonus * employees job title Employee % + Company&Vendor bonus * job title Company %. If base bonus is more than regular bonus, than multiply regular bonus * employees job title Employee % + Company&Vendor bonus * job title Company %.

Example:

**Bobby**

Base Bonus $50 < Regular Bonus $100

Find Bobby's Job title to determine Employee % & Company %

75% Employee % for Officers and 50% Company %

75% * $50 + 50% * ($200 Company & $0 Vendor) = $137.5

Final answer is $137.5 of base bonus if < regular bonus

Here is list of each formula by combo:

Combo 1:

```
=IF(Data!$C$1=1,Data!$B$3*Bonus!D2+Data!$B$4*(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2))
```

Combo 2:

```
=IF(Data!$C$1=2,IF(SUM(Bonus!B2:C2)<1,0,1)*Data!$B$6+Data!B5))
```

Combo 3:

```
=IF(Data!$C$1=3,IF(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,'Base Bonus'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)<VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Bonus!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,'Base Bonus'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)*Data!$B$3+Data!$B$4*(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2),VLOOKUP(A2,Bonus!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE)*Data!$B$3+Data!$B$4*(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2)))
```

Combo 5:

```
IF(Data!$C$1=5,IF(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,'Base Bonus'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)<VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Bonus!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,'Base Bonus'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Data!$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE),Data!$A$8:$C$11,2,FALSE)+(Bonus!E2+Bonus!E2)*VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Data!$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE),Data!$A$8:$C$11,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,Bonus!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Data!$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE),Data!$A$8:$C$11,2,FALSE)+(Bonus!E2+Bonus!E2)*VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Data!$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE),Data!$A$8:$C$11,3,FALSE)))
```

Hopefully this is a lot more clear than my initial post and can easily be replicated.  Let me know if you have any questions, Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean `A=1` and `A*D=2`? What do these rules mean? What do you mean by "combine formulas"? Some example data from your spreadsheet and example desired outcome would be helpful here.

Comment: I was trying to simplify it, but that did not seem to work very well.  I will work on editing the original post to make it more actionable.

Comment: @Hery0502 Yeah I think a more detailed breakdown with some fake data would be best here.... I will delete my answer for now as it is wrong, I'll check back after edit and see what I can do.

Comment: @RichardTompsett - Is there a way for me to post or send my workbook?  It will be hard to understand the post if I try to place all of the data in there, but can certainly try if that is the only option.

Comment: @Hery0502 Thanks, I'll take a look tomorrow if someone hasn't helped before then... Got some pressing work to do.

Comment: @RichardTompsett - Not a problem, appreciate you taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some issues in your formulas

1. Combo3 In the else option you have `A2` following the pattern it should be `Summary!A2`
2. Combo5 the sum is in the same cell you have `(Bonus!E2+Bonus!E2)` it should be `(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2)`
3. I didn't record the initial nested If to compare why it is not working. I got this:

Final Nested:

```
    =IF(Data!$C$1=1,Data!$B$3*Bonus!D2+Data!$B$4*(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2),IF(Data!$C$1=2,IF(SUM(Bonus!B2:C2)<1,0,1)*Data!$B$6+Data!B5,IF(Data!$C$1=3,IF(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,'Base Bonus'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)<VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Bonus!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,'Base Bonus'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)*Data!$B$3+Data!$B$4*(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2),VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Bonus!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE)*Data!$B$3+Data!$B$4*(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2)),IF(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,'Base Bonus'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)<VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Bonus!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,'Base Bonus'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Data!$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE),Data!$A$8:$C$11,2,FALSE)+(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2)*VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Data!$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE),Data!$A$8:$C$11,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B2,Bonus!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Data!$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE),Data!$A$8:$C$11,2,FALSE)+(Bonus!E2+Bonus!F2)*VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(Summary!A2,Data!$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE),Data!$A$8:$C$11,3,FALSE)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Its hard to post these questions without referring to the actual workbook, but the solution you posted is definitely a way to get around the nested IF statement that's a mile long.  Only issue is the shear amount of data I would have to do this for, but it might be the only option.

Comment: Oh I see, when I have this kind of functions I make a new table and split the formula in many fields. That allows me to see patterns to simplify the final equation. Then you can create a function with cases using VBA or a vlookup.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this help you. It worked in my excel file. Let me know if you need it.

Comment: It works exactly how I want it to, thank you so much for the patience and help!